# PHP JSON response normalization

Tags: php, json

I've got JSON response.
Almost all is correct, but SOME values need "addslashes" before I can decode without errors.

**http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/** servise says that the following is invalid:

"admiAmn":"DEEE\trtrtrtrtr",
And I agree with jsonformatter.

If I use addslashes, slashes will be added everywhere, and I need just to replace th following:

[NOT_SLASH]\[NOT_SLASH]

with:

[NOT_SLASH]\\[NOT_SLASH]

I can not either str_replace or addslashes, I must be shure that the '\' which is being replaced has no any '\' after and before it.

Thanks.
I would like to hear you thoughts and ideas.

Comment: Dont fiddle with the bad output, fix the source. JSON is such a simple thing; if your source isn't able to do it right ...it _can't_ be worth _anything_ ;-)

Comment: Well, a very simple regex with a negative lookbehind can sort that out, *but*... what if those slashes are for *valid escape sequences*? Come to that, isn't your example just a valid escape sequence? I thought `\t` was a horizontal tab in JSON, just like it is in JS and PHP...

Comment: Can i see a full sample of the response you got ??? Its its a bad output issue then it more than you using addslashes

Comment: Here is the complete example:   {"user":{"time":"1200","dps":[{"name":"d1","image":{"adminUsername":"EMO\admin"},"dpp":"%USERPROFILE%\\test.exe"}]}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace` to do the trick like this:

```
$in = '"admiAmn":"DEEE\trtrtrtrtr\\alma"';
$slash = preg_quote('\\');
echo preg_replace("#(?<!{$slash}){$slash}(?!{$slash})#", $slash.$slash, $in), "\n";
```

I've moved the escaped `\` to a variable to make it more readable. The pattern uses the negative [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) and [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) features to make this work.

However if you can, you should try fix the source instead of patching the output (at least file a bugreport of some kind), patching output can be really brittle.

Comment: Sorry, but **\t** does not mean tab character in **"admiAmn":"DEEE\trtrtrtrtr\\alma"**.

Comment: But this really helped:

`$slash    = preg_quote("\\");`
`$response = preg_replace("#(?<!{$slash}){$slash}(?!{$slash})#", $slash.$slash, $response);`

Comment: Hmm... consulted with the json documentation and I think you are right. If they encoded a `\t` then it should look like as `\\t` in the output. I think i've learned something today too. (-: (removing that part from the answer)